Standardize (rescale) after PCA to run a regression?
I standardized my panel data, applied PCA and extracted two principal components. Now I want to use them to run a fixed effects regression.
I have quite a few interactions (double and triple) between these two components and other variables, and I am concerned about the sign of the coefficients. The main issue is that all the variables that I used for PCA could only take positive values, and since I standardized them, now the components take both positive and negative values. Someone suggested me to standardize (rescale) the components again to prevent them from taking negative values and then run the regression, but I am skeptical about this. In short, should I do:
standardization -> PCA -> regression
or
standardization -> PCA -> standardization (rescaling) -> regression?
